# What will be the xpath?

Tags: xpath, jsoup

How can I get the element data using jsoup or xpath.
My requirement is 
if i have selected class='SecondClass' then how to find its parent "FirstClass". Means if  i  have selected class="SecondClass">yyyyyyyyy then how to find 
class="FirstClass">Hi element

```
            <div class="FirstClass">Hello</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">xyza</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">lllllllll</div>
            <div class="FirstClass">Hi</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">ooooooooo</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">yyyyyyyyy</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">ttttttttyt</div>
            <div class="FirstClass">HelloHi</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">xysefsfza</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">hohoho</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">xydadaza</div>
            <div class="SecondClass">new</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this XPath expression to get nearest preceding `<div>` element having class attribute value equals `FirstClass` :

```
/preceding-sibling::div[@class='FirstClass'][1]
```

With that, given XML data is as posted in question, and current element is this :

```
<div class="SecondClass">yyyyyyyyy</div>
```

XPath query above will return this element :

```
<div class="FirstClass">Hi</div>
```